# Local setting not found for host name

Tags: django, localhost

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/omairbukhari/env_justads/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/omairbukhari/justads/backend/AdEnhancers/settings.py", line 368, in <module>
    raise Exception("Local settings not found for host %s" % hostname)
Exception: Local settings not found for host unknown
```

Local host is not working, It was working perfectly fine I dont know what heppend, I was working on it just a few minutes ago, here is the traceback.

Comment: Did you use virtualenv or pyenv?

Comment: I use virtualenv

Comment: did you solve your problem? what env did you runserver?

Comment: Yes It is solved. Thanks